# DataLoader update = System.NullPointerException, Manual update = no error

Tags: apex, trigger, data-loader, update

I'm trying to run a set of updates to change a picklist field for our Opportunities, using Salesforce's DataLoader.

When I run the update, none of the records are updated and the results show the following error

> WE_MRFv2: execution of AfterUpdate, caused by: System.NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null. Trigger.WE_MRFv2: line 168, column 1

At line `Decimal annualTxnRev = o.Annual_transaction_volume__c*o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c;`

But when I manually update the same field in one of the Opportunities, from the list of records which I'm trying to update, there aren't any errors.

Whether I'm using DataLoader or doing a manual update, the `Ramp_Profile__c` field is the only field that I'm updating and I'm setting it to the same value in both cases.
So any Formula fields etc. which are being modified as a result of the change, should contain the same values, in both scenarios.

**EDIT**

I can also update the records using the DataLoader one at a time.

--

Does the DataLoader process records differently, in a way which could cause this issue?

In the below `Annual Transaction Volume` is a Formula field & `Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c` is a Currency field, neither field is null. The `Ramp_Profile__c` is being set to 'Standard' through the update.

Unfortunately there's two triggers which will influence the outcome when the code is made..

**trigger WE_OppUpdates on Opportunity (before insert, before update){**

```
    List<WEID__c> weids = WEID__c.getall().values();
    Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

    //add Opportunity Record Type Ids from Custom Setting to list of valid Ids      
    for(WEID__c weid : weids) {
        try{
            validRecordTypeIds.add(weid.WEOppId__c);
        }catch (System.StringException e) {
            System.debug(System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,'Invalid Record Type Id ' + weid.WEOppId__c);
        }
    }

    If(Trigger.isInsert){

        for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
            if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId))
            {
                Date cd = o.CloseDate;

                if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Immediate'){
                    o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addDays(15);
                    o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                    o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(3);
                    o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 37.5;

                }else if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Standard'){
                    o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addMonths(3);
                    o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                    o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(3);
                    o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 37.5;

                }else if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Medium'){
                    o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addMonths(3);
                    o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                    o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(6);
                    o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 25;

                }else{//'Extended' Ramp Profile
                    o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addMonths(3);
                    o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                    o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(12);
                    o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 20;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    If(Trigger.isUpdate){
                for(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
                    if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId))
                    {
                        Date cd = o.CloseDate;

                        Opportunity oldOpp = Trigger.oldMap.get(o.Id);

                        if(oldOpp.CloseDate != o.CloseDate
                           ||
                           oldOpp.Ramp_Profile__c != o.Ramp_Profile__c){
                               if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Immediate'){
                                   o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addDays(15);
                                   if(o.Implementation_Revenue__c.month() != oldOpp.Implementation_Revenue__c.month()
                                      ||
                                      o.Implementation_Revenue__c.year() != oldOpp.Implementation_Revenue__c.year()
                                      || 
                                      oldOpp.Implementation_Revenue__c == null){
                                          o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                                          o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(3);
                                          o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 90/2;
                                      }
                               }else if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Standard'){
                                   o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addMonths(3);
                                   o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                                   o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(3);
                                   o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 90/2;//1st MRF month set to 10%

                               }else if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Medium'){
                                   o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addMonths(3);
                                   o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                                   o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(6);
                                   o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 90/5;

                               }else{//'Extended' Ramp Profile
                                   o.Implementation_Revenue__c = cd.addMonths(3);
                                   o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();
                                   o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(12);
                                   o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c = 90/11;
                               }
                           }else if(oldOpp.Implementation_Revenue__c.month() != o.Implementation_Revenue__c.month()
                                    || 
                                    oldOpp.Implementation_Revenue__c.year() != o.Implementation_Revenue__c.year()){
                                        o.Revenue_Commencement__c = o.Implementation_Revenue__c.addMonths(1).toStartOfMonth();

                                        if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Immediate' || o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Standard'){
                                            o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(3);

                                        }else if(o.Ramp_Profile__c == 'Medium'){
                                            o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(6);

                                        }else{//'Extended' Ramp Profile
                                            o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.addMonths(12);
                                        }
                                    }
                    }
                }
    }

}
```

**trigger WE_MRFv2 on Opportunity (after insert, after update){**

```
    List<WEID__c> weids = WEID__c.getall().values();
    Set<Id> validRecordTypeIds = new Set<Id>();

    // add Opportunity Record Type Ids from Custom Setting to list of valid Ids      
    for(WEID__c weid : weids) {
        try {
            validRecordTypeIds.add(weid.WEOppId__c);
        } catch (System.StringException e) {
            System.debug(
                System.LoggingLevel.ERROR,
                'Invalid Record Type Id ' + weid.WEOppId__c);
        }
    }

    List<Opportunity> insOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> upOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    Map<Id,Integer> forecastDuration = new Map<Id,Integer>();
    Map<Integer,String> monthName = new Map<Integer,String>{1 => 'January', 2 => 'February', 3 => 'March', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'May', 6 => 'June', 7 => 'July', 8 => 'August', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'October', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December'};
    List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c> existMRFs = new List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c>();
    List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c> newMRFs = new List<Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c>();
    Map<Id,Decimal> oppsRampPer = new Map<Id,Decimal>();


    If(Trigger.isInsert){
        for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New){
            if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId) && o.Type != 'Existing Customer - Administration')
            {
                if(o.FSR_End_Date__c == null){
                    forecastDuration.put(o.Id,12);
                }else{
                    forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Revenue_Commencement__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));
                }
                insOpps.add(o);
            }
        }
    }

    If(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Opportunity o : Trigger.New){

            if(validRecordTypeIds.contains(o.RecordTypeId) && o.Type != 'Existing Customer - Administration')
            {
                Opportunity oldO = Trigger.OldMap.get(o.Id);

                if(oldO.CloseDate != o.CloseDate
                   ||
                   oldO.Ramp_Profile__c != o.Ramp_Profile__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Annual_Settlement_Value__c != o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Implementation_Revenue__c != o.Implementation_Revenue__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c != oldO.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c
                   ||
                   oldO.FSR_End_Date__c != o.FSR_End_Date__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c != o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c
                   ||
                   oldO.Annual_transaction_volume__c != o.Annual_transaction_volume__c)
                {
                if(o.FSR_End_Date__c == null){
                    forecastDuration.put(o.Id,12);
                }else{
                    forecastDuration.put(o.Id, o.Revenue_Commencement__c.monthsBetween(o.FSR_End_Date__c));
                }
                    upOpps.add(o);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(insOpps.size() > 0){

        for(Opportunity o : insOpps){

            Integer fcstDuration = forecastDuration.get(o.Id);
            if(fcstDuration > 0){

                Date rc = o.Revenue_Commencement__c;
                Decimal monthlySett = o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c/fcstDuration;
                Decimal annualTxns = o.Annual_transaction_volume__c;
                Decimal monthlyTxns = annualTxns/fcstDuration;
                Decimal annualTxnRev = o.Annual_transaction_volume__c*o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c;
                Decimal monthlyTxnRev = annualTxnRev/fcstDuration;

                //Ramp calculations
                Decimal increment = o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c/100;
                Integer rDur = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.monthsBetween(o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c);

                //FSR calculations
                Integer fsrDur = forecastDuration.get(o.Id) - rDur;

                //add Monthly Forecast records for 'ramp' months
                for(Integer m = 0; m < rDur; m++){

                    Decimal ramp = 0;

                    if(m == 0){
                        Decimal rampPer = 0.1;
                        ramp = rampPer;
                    }else if(increment*(m) >= 0.1){
                        Decimal rampPer = increment*(m);
                        ramp = rampPer;
                    }else{
                        Decimal rampPer = 0.1;
                        ramp = rampPer;
                    }

                    Decimal monthTxns = monthlyTxns*ramp;
                    Decimal monthSett = monthlySett*ramp;
                    Decimal monthTxnRev = monthlyTxnRev*ramp;

                    Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                    fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                    fm.Account__c = o.AccountId;
                    fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    fm.Name = monthName.get(rc.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ rc.addMonths(m).year();
                    fm.Revenue_Date__c = rc.addMonths(m+1).toStartOfMonth()-1;
                    fm.Transactions__c = monthTxns;
                    fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = monthSett;
                    fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = monthTxnRev;

                    newMRFs.add(fm);
                }

                //add Monthly Forecast Records for rFSR Months
                for(Integer m = rDur; m < rDur + fsrDur; m++){

                    Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                    fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                    fm.Account__c = o.AccountId;
                    fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    fm.Name = monthName.get(rc.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ rc.addMonths(m).year();
                    fm.Revenue_Date__c = rc.addMonths(m+1).toStartOfMonth()-1;
                    fm.Transactions__c = monthlyTxns;
                    fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = monthlySett;
                    fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = monthlyTxnRev;

                    newMRFs.add(fm);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(upOpps.size() > 0){

        for(Opportunity o : [SELECT Id,
                            (SELECT Id FROM Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r) FROM Opportunity
                              WHERE Id = :upOpps[0].Id])
        {               
            if(o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r.size()> 0){
                existMRFs.addAll(o.Monthly_Revenue_Forecasts__r);
            }
        }
        delete existMRFs;

        for(Opportunity o : upOpps){

            Integer fcstDuration = forecastDuration.get(o.Id);
            if(fcstDuration > 0){

                Date rc = o.Revenue_Commencement__c;
                Decimal monthlySett = o.Annual_Settlement_Value__c/fcstDuration;
                Decimal annualTxns = o.Annual_transaction_volume__c;
                Decimal monthlyTxns = annualTxns/fcstDuration;
   /*ERROR>*/   Decimal annualTxnRev = o.Annual_transaction_volume__c*o.Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c;
                Decimal monthlyTxnRev = annualTxnRev/fcstDuration;

                //Ramp calculations
                Decimal increment = o.Implementation_Revenue_as_a_of_FSR__c/100;
                Integer rDur = o.Revenue_Commencement__c.monthsBetween(o.Forecast_Full_Service_Revenue_Date__c);

                //FSR calculations
                Integer fsrDur = forecastDuration.get(o.Id) - rDur;

                //add Monthly Forecast records for 'ramp' months
                for(Integer m = 0; m < rDur; m++){

                    Decimal ramp = 0;

                    if(m == 0){
                        Decimal rampPer = 0.1;
                        ramp = rampPer;
                    }else if(increment*(m) >= 0.1){
                        Decimal rampPer = increment*(m);
                        ramp = rampPer;
                    }else{
                        Decimal rampPer = 0.1;
                        ramp = rampPer;
                    }

                    Decimal monthTxns = monthlyTxns*ramp;
                    Decimal monthSett = monthlySett*ramp;
                    Decimal monthTxnRev = monthlyTxnRev*ramp;

                    Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                    fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                    fm.Account__c = o.AccountId;
                    fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    fm.Name = monthName.get(rc.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ rc.addMonths(m).year();
                    fm.Revenue_Date__c = rc.addMonths(m+1).toStartOfMonth()-1;
                    fm.Transactions__c = monthTxns;
                    fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = monthSett;
                    fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = monthTxnRev;

                    newMRFs.add(fm);
                }

                //add Monthly Forecast Records for rFSR Months
                for(Integer m = rDur; m < rDur + fsrDur; m++){

                    Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c fm = new Monthly_Revenue_Forecast__c();
                    fm.Opportunity__c = o.Id;
                    fm.Account__c = o.AccountId;
                    fm.CurrencyIsoCode = o.CurrencyIsoCode;
                    fm.Name = monthName.get(rc.addMonths(m).month()) +' '+ rc.addMonths(m).year();
                    fm.Revenue_Date__c = rc.addMonths(m+1).toStartOfMonth()-1;
                    fm.Transactions__c = monthlyTxns;
                    fm.Monthly_Settlement1__c = monthlySett;
                    fm.Transaction_Revenue__c = monthlyTxnRev;

                    newMRFs.add(fm);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    insert newMRFS;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Triggers run the same for UI updates, API updates, and code updates (e.g. Visualforce, Apex Code). There is never a time when they'll behave differently simply because you're in a particular mode of operation (the code itself really has no way of even knowing much beyond "am I in a test method or async method").

You're not checking to make sure that `Annual_Transaction_Volume__c` and `Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c` values are not null. It's entirely possible you're trying to upload a null value for either of these fields. In other words, the problem is data related, not necessarily code related. You *should* check to see if those fields are null before attempting to do math with them, and then respond appropriately (either assume 0, or abort early).

Comment: Thanks for this but I'm literally making the change to the one field using the DataLoader or manually (so the field values are all the same) and the outcome is different. I guess this means it's going to be pretty difficult to figure out the cause of the issue. I'll update the post if I can figure it out.

Comment: @AlexS You'll want to start from the beginning, though. The error tells you where the NPE is, and it must be one of those two fields. You might try using some asserts to see which field it happens to be.

Comment: Will do, just to check, the way that the DataLoader manages batch updates to records shouldn't cause any issues should it? I'm assuming that the behavior's the same as applying DML statement for a list?

Comment: @AlexS Exactly. The system behaves identically in both cases. I don't suppose you have any workflow rules with field updates, perhaps, causing the fields to be cleared out? That'd be one possible cause.

Comment: I have a field update for `Monthly_Txn_Revenue_POS__c` but it's setting the field value to 1 so I'm assuming that, that won't cause an issue. Thanks for the suggestion though.